# MySQL view with unique column

Tags: mysql, view, unique

I created a view in MySQL database :

| word | language |
| --- | --- |
| hello | 1 |
| bonjour | 2 |
| ola | 3 |

I would like to set both column as UNIQUE to prevent having the same word twice in the same language, to avoir this:

| word | language |
| --- | --- |
| hello | 1 |
| hello | 1 |

But allow this:

| word | language |
| --- | --- |
| hello | 1 |
| hello | 4 |

This is not a table, this is a view. How can I do it?

Comment: If the view returns only these 2 columns then add distinct to your code: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: use select distinct word,language from tbl as suggested up